# Haxe: How to check if a variable is a function

Tags: types, haxe

I would like to see if a Dynamic variable in Haxe is a Function.

Using `Std.is(v, Function)` does not work as Function is not a recognized key word for types.

I tried fooling around with `$type(v)` but it doesn't seem to actually return a string. `Sys.println($type(v));` does output `<function>` but it doesn't seem like I can work with it.

I also tried to use `Std.is` with `typedef` but no luck as `typedef`s are not variables.

TDLR: I want a function that takes a variable and outputs a boolean based on if it is a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`Reflect.isFunction()`](https://api.haxe.org/Reflect.html#isFunction).

Comment: That is exactly it, I knew there was something but I had forgotten it since the last time I was using Haxe and the documentation is a bit difficult to search. Thanks so much.